# Install MODI quiet with Sharepoint already installed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

For a project, I need to install MsOfficeDocumentImaging (MODI) quietly through an installer. Me and my colleague have found out that it comes as a part of Sharepoint Designer 2007 and there doesn't seem to be a standalone installer for it. So after some digging, we extracted the installer, then installed the correct part using:

```
setup.exe /config config.xml
```

Using the config file config.xml with the content:

```
<Configuration Product="SharePointDesigner">

<Display Level="None" CompletionNotice="No" SuppressModal="Yes" AcceptEula="Yes" />

</Configuration>
```

This will work fine if no instance of the SharePointDesigner is on the system, but if SharePoint was already installed without MODI (which is unfortunately the default setting for a SharePoint installation), the installation will simply complete without doing anything.

In the same fashion, using the `/adminfile modi.msp` command will not work if SharePoint is already installed.

We don't want to uninstall/reinstall sharepoint, because it would run the risk of deleting other components of SharePoint that the users/admins manually installed before.

Is there any way of **silently** installing MODI without relying on SharePoint not already being installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we didn't find a way to install MODI without SharePoint Designer, but we managed to find a solution for the problem.

By checking if SharePoint Designer is installed using the registry key it sets on installation, which can be found under

```
SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\12.0\SharePoint Designer\InstallRoot
```

We switched between either installing SPD using our config.xml file, or, if it was already installed, PATCHING MODI in using a .msp file that can be created via the normal setup.

Answer (score 0):

I edit documents for my job since 2010 and really rely on MODI, but it's getting harder and harder to find and obtain if I have a clean install going on or a newer operating system.  I can still find rogue sharepoint installers out there or even old MS office 2007 where i can do a custom install and get modi installed, but, are there any other options out there that can work with .tif to manipulate multiple pages within a multi page tif, flip 180 degrees, annotate, cut and paste and remove page sections and paste into a new file/filename?  very important when cutting up a multipage fax off a server that needs to have sections divided up.